# Ошибка при использовании @model_validator в pydantic

Tags: python, pydantic, pydantic-2.x

Вот сам код:

```
from gpt_index import SimpleDirectoryReader, GPTListIndex, GPTSimpleVectorIndex, LLMPredictor, PromptHelper
from langchain import OpenAI
import gradio as gr
import sys
import os
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator

os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = 'api'

class BasePromptTemplate(BaseModel):
    @validator('*', pre=True, skip_on_failure=True)
    def check_root_validator(cls, value):
        return value

def construct_index(directory_path):
    max_input_size = 4096
    num_outputs = 512
    max_chunk_overlap = 20
    chunk_size_limit = 600

    prompt_helper = PromptHelper(max_input_size, num_outputs, max_chunk_overlap, chunk_size_limit=chunk_size_limit)

    llm_predictor = LLMPredictor(llm=OpenAI(temperature=0.7, model_name="text-davinci-003", max_tokens=num_outputs))

    documents = SimpleDirectoryReader(directory_path).load_data()

    index = GPTSimpleVectorIndex(documents, llm_predictor=llm_predictor, prompt_helper=prompt_helper)

index.save_to_disk('index.json')

return index

def chatbot(input_text):
    index = GPTSimpleVectorIndex.load_from_disk('index.json')
    response = index.query(input_text, response_mode="compact")
    return response.response

iface = gr.Interface(fn=chatbot,
                     inputs=gr.inputs.Textbox(lines=7, label="Enter your text"),
                     outputs="text",
                     title="Custom-trained AI Chatbot")

index = construct_index("docs")
iface.launch(share=True)
```

Вот ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/sawag/Desktop/Home Work/Kwork/WhatsApp bot/generated_date/app.py", line 1, in <module>
    from gpt_index import SimpleDirectoryReader, GPTListIndex, GPTSimpleVectorIndex, LLMPredictor, PromptHelper
  File "C:\Users\sawag\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\gpt_index\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from gpt_index.embeddings.langchain import LangchainEmbedding
  File "C:\Users\sawag\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\gpt_index\embeddings\langchain.py", line 6, in <module>
    from langchain.embeddings.base import Embeddings as LCEmbeddings
  File "C:\Users\sawag\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\langchain\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from langchain.agents import MRKLChain, ReActChain, SelfAskWithSearchChain
  File "C:\Users\sawag\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\langchain\agents\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from langchain.agents.agent import Agent
  File "C:\Users\sawag\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\langchain\agents\agent.py", line 10, in <module>
    from langchain.chains.base import Chain
  File "C:\Users\sawag\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from langchain.chains.conversation.base import ConversationChain
  File "C:\Users\sawag\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\conversation\base.py", line 7, in <module>       
    from langchain.chains.conversation.memory import ConversationBufferMemory
  File "C:\Users\sawag\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\conversation\memory.py", line 7, in <module>     
    from langchain.chains.conversation.prompt import SUMMARY_PROMPT
  File "C:\Users\sawag\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\conversation\prompt.py", line 2, in <module>     
    from langchain.prompts.prompt import PromptTemplate
  File "C:\Users\sawag\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\langchain\prompts\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from langchain.prompts.base import BasePromptTemplate
  File "C:\Users\sawag\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\langchain\prompts\base.py", line 35, in <module>
    class BasePromptTemplate(BaseModel, ABC):
  File "C:\Users\sawag\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\langchain\prompts\base.py", line 41, in BasePromptTemplate        
    @root_validator()
  File "C:\Users\sawag\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pydantic\deprecated\class_validators.py", line 228, in root_validator
    raise PydanticUserError(
pydantic.errors.PydanticUserError: If you use `@root_validator` with pre=False (the default) you MUST specify `skip_on_failure=True`. Note that `@root_validator` is deprecated and should be replaced with `@model_validator`.

For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.0.1/u/root-validator-pre-skip
```

Я получил сообщение об ошибке об устаревшем декораторе и что его имя надо сменить, но ошибка так и не ушла.

Answer (score 0):

На версии Pydantic 1 (`pip install -U "pydantic<2"`):

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, root_validator


class BasePromptTemplate(BaseModel):
    @root_validator
    def check_root_validator(cls, value):
        return value
```

На версии Pydantic 2 примерно то же самое, только добавляете `skip_on_failure=True`, как написано в тексте ошибки у вас:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, root_validator


class BasePromptTemplate(BaseModel):
    @root_validator(skip_on_failure=True)
    def check_root_validator(cls, value):
        return value
```

Будет предупреждение:

```
PydanticDeprecatedSince20: Pydantic V1 style `@root_validator` validators are deprecated. You should migrate to Pydantic V2 style `@model_validator` validators, see the migration guide for more details. Deprecated in Pydantic V2.0 to be removed in V3.0. See Pydantic V2 Migration Guide at https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.0.1/migration/
  @root_validator(skip_on_failure=True)
```

Вкратце, там написано, что `root_validator` будет удален в Pydantic 3.0, но в принципе пока это предупреждением можно игнорировать. Но нужно иметь в виду, что в какой-то момент придется заменить `root_validator` на `model_validator`.

Через новый декоратор `@model_validator` (см. документацию: [Model validators](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/validators/#model-validators)):

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, model_validator


class BasePromptTemplate(BaseModel):
    @model_validator(mode="before")
    def check_root_validator(cls, value):
        return value
```

`mode` влияет на то, когда и на данных в каком виде будет происходить валидация. Если `"before"`, то на сырых данных (в виде словаря), до того как они будут конвертированы в модель - это аналогично тому, как работает `root_validator`. Если `"after"`, то уже на данных распакованных в вашу модель.